# Join creates .x and .y column but they have identical content - why?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am confused about the output I am getting from a join command in dplyr like this:

```
d <- d1 %>% left_join(d2, by="someColumn")
```

The resulting df is what I expected except a column "someOtherColumn" is present as "someOtherColumn.x" and "someOtherColumn.y". I know that this is expected if the value in someColumn (on which I join) has diferent values in d1 and d2 but when I try to look at the rows affected with this:

```
d %>% filter( someOtherColumn.x != someOtherColumn.y)
```

I get no rows.
How is that possible? Why might dplyr create the .x/.y columns for a column that has identical values in the two dataframes in the given join? It hasn't created .x/.y for any of the other columns.

Apologies for not showing any data. I can't share the actual data and I can't mock up a dataset that reproduces the error because I don't know what causes it.

Comment: In that case you should actually join by `someOtherColumn` as well. `d <- d1 %>% left_join(d2, by=c("someColumn", "someOtherColumn"))`

Comment: what I'm trying to understand if why this is happening if the two columns are actually identical. It should not happen or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you will only get .x and .y if the values aren't unique. You didn't join by `someOtherColumn` and it is in both datasets so it will give them both unique names with .x and .y, if you don't want that just drop one from one of the datasets.

Comment: @Mike I think you are right. I misunderstood the docs. It does actually create a .x and .y for all columns that exist in both sets. I thought it would only do so where there are some different variables. My mistake, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take this simple example.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 1:4, c = rnorm(4))
df2 <- data.frame(a = 4:1, b = 4:1, c = rnorm(4))
df1

#  a b           c
#1 1 1 -0.56047565
#2 2 2 -0.23017749
#3 3 3  1.55870831
#4 4 4  0.07050839

df2
#  a b          c
#1 4 4  0.1292877
#2 3 3  1.7150650
#3 2 2  0.4609162
#4 1 1 -1.2650612
```

Notice the values in column `a` and `b` are the same in both the dataframes (although the order is different).

When you join only by `a` you get

```
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = 'a')
#  a b.x         c.x b.y        c.y
#1 1   1 -0.56047565   1 -1.2650612
#2 2   2 -0.23017749   2  0.4609162
#3 3   3  1.55870831   3  1.7150650
#4 4   4  0.07050839   4  0.1292877
```

You have told to join only by `a` so it will match only `a` column, rest of the columns are treated differently even if their values are the same. Hence you get `b.x`, `b.y` as well `c.x` and `c.y`.

If you want that `b.x` and `b.y` should not be generated as they are the same specify it in `by`.

```
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c('a', 'b'))

#  a b         c.x        c.y
#1 1 1 -0.56047565 -1.2650612
#2 2 2 -0.23017749  0.4609162
#3 3 3  1.55870831  1.7150650
#4 4 4  0.07050839  0.1292877
```

Now you get only `c.x` and `c.y` additional columns.

Comment: yes, sorry, it was my misunderstanding of dplyr behaviour. I thought it would only create the .x/.y columns if necessary due to some values differing but it simply does this with every column that is present in both dataframes. Sorry to have wasted your time but thank you for the detailed answer!